# Resolving async function in action creator

Tags: angular, asynchronous, redux, thunk

I'm trying to resolve this async call in my action creator before the state is updated. I tried to implement redux thunk but I am fairly new to it and angular4+ as a whole.

Here is what my action creators look like:

```
@Injectable() 
export class IndexActions {
  constructor(
    private _cloudReadService: CloudReadService
  ) {}
  static UPDATE_INDEX = 'UPDATE_INDEX';

  updateIndex(): ActionWithPayload {
    return {
      type: IndexActions.UPDATE_INDEX,
      payload: this._cloudReadService.getRecordsByOwner()
        .then(response => {return response})
        .catch(err => console.log)
    }
  }
}
```

The main issue I had with thunk is that my service methods were not defined within the actual thunk.

Here is what the service basically looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class CloudReadService {
  constructor() {
  }

  getRecordsByOwner(): any {
    return firebase.database()
      .ref('lists/records/owners')
      .orderByChild('ownerName')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
          /* process response */
          return processedResponse;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I guess my question really is how can I use service methods within redux middleware, or is there an alternative way?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do it is by dispatching three separate actions.

Adding the `thunk` middleware to to your store will allow you to return a function with a dispatch parameter from your action so you can dispatch multiple actions.

```
import thunkMiddlware from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
  // reducer
  rootReducer,
  // preloadedState
  undefined,
  // compose simply enables us to apply several store enhancers
  // Right now, we are only using applyMiddlware, so this is
  // just future-proofing our application
  compose(
    // Middlware can intercept dispatched actions before they reach the reducer
    // in order to modify it in some way
    applyMiddleware(
      // Thunk allows functions to be returned from action creators
      // so we can do things like dispatch multiple actions in a 
      // single action creator for async actions
      thunkMiddlware
    )
  )
);
```

Then you can dispatch each stage of the request appropriately by calling only `updateIndex()`

```
updateIndexStart(): Action {
 return {
   type: 'UPDATE_INDEX_START'
 };
}

updateIndexSuccess(response): ActionWithPayload  {
 return {
   type: 'UPDATE_INDEX_SUCCESS',
   payload: response
 };
}

updateIndexError(err): ActionWithPayload  {
 return {
   type: 'UPDATE_INDEX_ERROR',
   payload: err
 };
}

updateIndex() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(updateIndexStart());
    cloudReadService.getRecordsByOwner()
      .then(response => dispatch(updateIndexSuccess(response)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(updateIndexError(err)));
  };
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried something like this before but it didn't work. This time around it did! I had to change a few things though. I had to dispatch the success and error functions as well as prepending their calls with 'this.'